# Filtering DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView in my winform along with a TextBox to search in the DataGridView. The DataGridView has a CheckBox column. This is how my code looks:

```
 Imports System.ComponentModel
 imports system.Data.sqlclient

 Public Class MyForm
    Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data source=" & My.Settings.sqlserver & ", " & My.Settings.sqlport & ";Network Library=DBMSSOCN;initial catalog=" & My.Settings.dbname & ";User id=" & My.Settings.Username & ";Password=" & My.Settings.Password & ";")

    Dim ds As New DataSet

    Private Sub filterdata(valuetosearch As String)
        Dim srq As String = "Select * from Contacts where CONCAT([Unique id],Prefix,[First name],[Last name],Gender,Title,Company,Phone,Mobile,Fax,[b.email],[p.email],Reference,Address,[Address 2],Country,City,Zip,Facebook,GooglePlus,Instagram,Twitter,Website,Salary,Currency,[Group],[Id/Status],Note,[Added by]) like '%" & valuetosearch & "%' "
         Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(srq, con)
         adapter.Fill(ds, "Contacts_table")
         userdatagrid.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
   End Sub
   Private Sub searcgcon_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles searcgcon.TextChanged
       If searcgcon.Text = "" Then
           filterdata("")
           entrylabel.Text = "There are/is " & userdatagrid.Rows.Count & " contact entries"
      Else
         filterdata(searcgcon.Text)
         entrylabel.Text = "There are/is " & userdatagrid.Rows.Count & " contact entries that contain your query :" & searcgcon.Text
      End If
  End Sub

  Private sub refresh_click()handles refresh.click
      filterdata("")
  end sub
 End class
```

I have corrected an earlier problem (see [How to maintain datagridview checkstate when filtering VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46952274/how-to-maintain-datagridview-checkstate-when-filtering-vb-net)).

Now the problem I have is when I press a button that triggers "filterdata", e.g. the refresh button or even when I click/type something in the TextBox (the one used to filter), the DataGridView keeps adding rows of the same data. Please tell me where I'm wrong.

I posted this on other sites. One guy said that my filterdata's code should be in the form's Load event. If i do that then I would face some problems like :

1. I wouldn't have a sub called filterdata
2. If I don't have that sub, how am i supposed to use it in the TextBox TextChanged event?

If i am still wrong, please correct me. I am just a student!

(P.S. The database contains an Image column which i can't include in the srq string as it gives me an error on adapter.fill saying "Operand type clash : Image is incompatible with nvarchar")

Comment: The code in your question is a bit of a mess. You have a Sub `filterdata` followed by some lines of code that are not inside any method (which is not allowed), followed by an invalid event handler. Please edit the code so that it is valid and we know what is going on.

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint in your filterdata procedure. Most likely this will tell you 'something' about why it's being called or where it's being called from

Comment: Sir, the filterdata is being called from one event, that is the textbox's textchanged event

Comment: Please re-read the post.....i arranged the codes properly

Comment: I thought I saw a click event that called filterdata too. Anyway, try this.  Try setting the DataSource property of your grid `userdatagrid.DataSource = Nothing` directly before you set the DataSource property to srq query results.  Also, you might try implementing a BindingSource. The lack of a BindingSource can cause unwanted behavior when refreshing a DataSource

Comment: You are not filtering anything - you are running new queries.  You could/should apply a filter to the datasource instead.  TextChanged is going to fire (and run a new query) every time the user presses a key, I would add a button for them to click.  I am also not sure how that code double up rows in the dataset.

Comment: ...And please dont make sock puppet accounts to ask **[the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46952274/1070452)** just a few hours later

Comment: @Plutonix While it does seem odd that the OP created a new account to ask this question, it does not appear to be the same as the earlier one (which OP says is solved).

Comment: @Plutonix , i did what u said (userdatagrid.datasource=nothing). Now another strange thing is happening.Please see sandy's comment and my reply.

Comment: Thats **not at all** what I suggested.  Rather than run a query to get the same data with a different WHERE clause, actually filter the datatable you get,

Comment: sir please see my reply on sandy's comment. I added two screen shots.Can u explain those ? (i am really sorry to bother u so much sir, i am a student, maybe the dumbest one)

Comment: Every datatable has a built in `DataView`.  1) Load all the rows into the datatable. 2) Change the `DataTable,DefaultView,RowFilter` to actually filter what is shown.  No need to run new queries.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 1):

Update your filterdata method with below code -

```
Private Sub filterdata(valuetosearch As String)
    userdatagrid.DataSource = Nothing
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim srq As String = "Select * from Contacts where CONCAT([Unique id],Prefix,[First name],[Last name],Gender,Title,Company,Phone,Mobile,Fax,[b.email],[p.email],Reference,Address,[Address 2],Country,City,Zip,Facebook,GooglePlus,Instagram,Twitter,Website,Salary,Currency,[Group],[Id/Status],Note,[Added by]) like '%" & valuetosearch & "%' "
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(srq, con)
    adapter.Fill(ds, "Contacts_table")
    userdatagrid.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
End Sub
```

You have to reset you Dataset and Grid Datasource on every text change.

Comment: i used this code.Something strange happened . in my textchange event i used the code mentioned in the post . While using ur code along with my code(only the textchange event's code),if i click on the textbox, the first row of my dgvw(which is an image row that loads image from the same sql connection)becomes blank and it's width increases...here's a screent shot : before click : [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9Q3-Og5WXqYZ0RTUF84S05rRFE)  after click [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9Q3-Og5WXqYTkxpT3FqVDd3Z1E)

Comment: May be because your initial binding source is different than the above SQL query. In above SQL query I am not seeing any column for Pic. You have to use the similar SQL query here too.

Comment: i can't use the Pic columns in the connectionstring as it gives me error on adapter.fill saying "Operand type clash : Image is incompatible with nvarchar"

Comment: @ronnie - You don't have to use Pic column in connectionstring. Is Contacts table have Image column and is it the part of "Select * from Contacts"? I suggestion, please check the initial binding.

Comment: sir, the there's only one databinding and that's in the filterdata evemt.I tried including pic column in the sqr string but the same exception error occures! and yes , contact table has image column and it's name is PIC